# Changing the name of a binary packaged application and its evoking command

Tags: linux, package, compilation, rpm, deb

I have taken the source code of a large C project, App A, and made modifications to it to produce my version, App B. Both App A and App B compile cleanly on Debian and Red Hat and now I would like to build binary packages for both platforms.

The last modification I need to make is ensuring App B can be installed alongside App A without any interference. I should be able to evoke both `app-a` and `app-b` in the terminal and have both be listed as separate software items in whatever desktop environment is present.

The projects have a `debian/` folder (containing `rules`, `control`, etc.) and an `rpm/` folder containing a `SPEC` file. Currently, building and installing the .rpm and .deb packages works except that App B is recognized as App A and therefore does not meet the aforementioned requirements. `ldd` shows the programs have the same exact dependencies and I am not able to pursue static linking of libraries.

**I want to have an application and a modified version of that application be installed and recognized as separate applications from the .deb and .rpm files I build.**

What modifications do I need to make to my project to achieve the desired outcome? Please **be specific** as I have already researched package building but am unable to find material addressing this issue.

Comment: For the RH side, you'd have to edit the `.spec` file you noted and re-run `rpmbuild`. Lots of tutorials out there, but a first pass of "search and replace" would be a great start.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer for Debian packaging.

1. Make sure that the names of the binary executable that you create in both variants are different.  E.g. variant "A" will have an executable `/usr/bin/app-a` and variant "B" will have `/usr/bin/app-b`.  That should be obvious, because otherwise you won't be able to have both of them installed at the same time.
2. If your software includes other files, such as libraries or other resources, these need to go into different directories as well, for example `/usr/lib/app-a/...` and `/usr/lib/app-b`
3. In each project, edit the `debian/control` file and change the *name* of the binary package that gets created.  The name is the value of the `Package:` field.  Also, you will need to change the name of the *source package* (`Source:` field, usually at the very top of `debian/control`).
4. (optional) If the two variants share most files, and only the executable (`/usr/bin/app-{a,b}`) are different, you might want to combine both in one source package, and build *three* binary packages from that single source package: one package with the files that are shared by both projects (`Package: app-common`), and one for each variant (`Package: app-a` and `Package: app-b`).  You will then need a `Makefile` that will build both variants, and write configuration files for `dh_install` that sort the files into the correct directories (`app-a` needs to go into `debian/app-a/usr/bin` and analogous for `app-b`).